# quicklisp to install and use cl-dbi failed with error - Error opening shared object "libmysqlclient_r.so":

Tags: mysql, lisp, common-lisp, clsql

I want to use cl-dbi to connect mysql.

After install cl-dbi on sbcl with quicklisp, try to connect to mysql but failed with following error:

```
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))


T
* (ql:quickload :cl-dbi)
To load "cl-dbi":
  Load 2 ASDF systems:
    alexandria closer-mop
  Install 6 Quicklisp releases:
    cl-annot cl-dbi cl-syntax named-readtables
    split-sequence trivial-types
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/split-sequence/2012-07-03/split-sequence-1.1.tgz">
; 3.78KB
==================================================
3,872 bytes in 0.01 seconds (420.14KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/cl-annot/2015-04-07/cl-annot-20150407-git.tgz">
; 9.80KB
==================================================
10,039 bytes in 0.00 seconds (9803.71KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/trivial-types/2012-04-07/trivial-types-20120407-git.tgz">
; 3.15KB
==================================================
3,228 bytes in 0.00 seconds (0.00KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/named-readtables/2015-03-02/named-readtables-20150302-git.tgz">
; 31.96KB
==================================================
32,732 bytes in 0.37 seconds (86.86KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/cl-syntax/2015-04-07/cl-syntax-20150407-git.tgz">
; 3.03KB
==================================================
3,102 bytes in 0.00 seconds (3029.30KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/cl-dbi/2015-04-07/cl-dbi-20150407-git.tgz">
; 11.13KB
==================================================
11,393 bytes in 0.71 seconds (15.76KB/sec)
; Loading "cl-dbi"
[package trivial-types]...........................
[package editor-hints.named-readtables]...........
[package editor-hints.named-readtables]...........
[package cl-syntax]...............................
[package cl-annot.util]...........................
[package cl-annot.core]...........................
[package cl-annot.expand].........................
[package cl-annot.syntax].........................
[package cl-annot.helper].........................
[package cl-annot]................................
[package cl-annot.std]............................
[package cl-annot.eval-when]......................
[package cl-annot.doc]............................
[package cl-annot.class]..........................
[package cl-annot.slot]...........................
[package split-sequence]..........................
[package closer-mop]..............................
[package closer-common-lisp]......................
[package closer-common-lisp-user].................
[package dbi.error]...............................
[package dbi.driver]..............................
[package dbi].
(:CL-DBI)
* (defvar *connection*
    (dbi:connect :mysql
                 :database-name "dbname"
                 :username "username"
                 :password "pwd"))
To load "dbd-mysql":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    dbd-mysql
; Loading "dbd-mysql"
To load "cl-mysql":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    alexandria
  Install 4 Quicklisp releases:
    babel cffi cl-mysql trivial-features
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/trivial-features/2015-01-13/trivial-features-20150113-git.tgz">
; 10.22KB
==================================================
10,465 bytes in 0.00 seconds (10219.73KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/babel/2014-12-17/babel-20141217-git.tgz">
; 243.81KB
==================================================
249,666 bytes in 6.30 seconds (38.73KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/cffi/2014-11-06/cffi_0.14.0.tgz">
; 207.73KB
==================================================
212,717 bytes in 9.06 seconds (22.92KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/cl-mysql/2015-03-02/cl-mysql-20150302-git.tgz">
; 24.99KB
==================================================
25,594 bytes in 0.15 seconds (165.52KB/sec)
; Loading "cl-mysql"
[package babel-encodings].........................
[package babel]...................................
..................................................
[package cffi-sys]................................
[package cffi]....................................
..................................................
[package cffi-features]...........................
[package com.hackinghat.cl-mysql-system].....
debugger invoked on a LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {B3E2369}>:
  Unable to load foreign library (LIBMYSQLCLIENT).
  Error opening shared object "libmysqlclient_r.so":
  libmysqlclient_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Try loading the foreign library again.
  1: [USE-VALUE                    ] Use another library instead.
  2: [TRY-RECOMPILING              ] Recompile system and try loading it again
  3: [RETRY                        ] Retry
                                     loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cl-mysql" "system">.
  4: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating
                                     loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cl-mysql" "system">
                                     as having been successful.
  5:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  6: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  7: [ABORT                        ] Give up on "cl-mysql"
  8:                                 Give up on "dbd-mysql"
  9:                                 Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(CFFI::FL-ERROR "Unable to load foreign library (~A).~%  ~A" LIBMYSQLCLIENT "Error opening shared object \"libmysqlclient_r.so\":
  libmysqlclient_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.")
```

Environment info:
OS: debian 8.1
mysql: 5.5.43-0+deb8u1
sbcl: SBCL 1.2.4.debian

Also failed to use cl-mysql clsql.

Anyone can give some clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After google, following suggestion from [post](https://thefreecountry.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/common-lisp-mysql-and-opensuse/) and issue is fixed.

```
> $ sudo find / -name *libmysqlclient* /usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient18
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.0.0
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.42-1_i386.deb
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.43-0+deb8u1_i386.deb
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.postinst
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.postrm
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.list
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.shlibs
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/libmysqlclient18:i386.md5sums
```

Just create libmysqlclient_r.so as link to libmysqlclient.so.18

```
$ sudo ln /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so
```

After that, execute cl-dbi example and it runs successfully.

```
* (ql:quickload :cl-dbi)
To load "cl-dbi":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-dbi
; Loading "cl-dbi"

(:CL-DBI)
* (defvar *connection*
  (dbi:connect :mysql
               :database-name "db-name"
               :username "dbuser"
               :password "dbpwd"))

To load "dbd-mysql":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    dbd-mysql
; Loading "dbd-mysql"
...........
*CONNECTION*
* (setf query (dbi:prepare *connection*
             "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE \"%version%\";"))
; in: SETF QUERY
;     (SETF QUERY
;             (DBI.DRIVER:PREPARE *CONNECTION*
;                                 "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE \"%version%\";"))
; ==>
;   (SETQ QUERY
;           (DBI.DRIVER:PREPARE *CONNECTION*
;                               "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE \"%version%\";"))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: QUERY
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     QUERY
;   caught 1 WARNING condition

#<DBD.MYSQL:<DBD-MYSQL-QUERY> {C3FF761}>
* (setf result (dbi:execute query))

; in: SETF RESULT
;     (DBI.DRIVER:EXECUTE QUERY)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: QUERY

;     (SETF RESULT (DBI.DRIVER:EXECUTE QUERY))
; ==>
;   (SETQ RESULT (DBI.DRIVER:EXECUTE QUERY))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: RESULT
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variables:
;     QUERY RESULT
;   caught 2 WARNING conditions

#<DBD.MYSQL:<DBD-MYSQL-QUERY> {C3FF761}>
* (loop for row = (dbi:fetch result)
       while row
       do (format t "~A~%" row))

; in: LOOP FOR
;     (DBI.DRIVER:FETCH RESULT)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: RESULT
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     RESULT
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
(Variable_name innodb_version Value 5.5.43)
(Variable_name protocol_version Value 10)
(Variable_name slave_type_conversions Value NIL)
(Variable_name version Value 5.5.43-0+deb8u1)
(Variable_name version_comment Value (Debian))
(Variable_name version_compile_machine Value i686)
(Variable_name version_compile_os Value debian-linux-gnu)
NIL
*
```